# How can I make CMD load normal system commands by default? (command prompt / powershell)

Tags: command-line, powershell, environment-variables

Please see below screenshot, this is pretty much self explanatory.  All default programs in System32 aren't being loaded and can't run unless I specify the exact directory and path of the program

[image]

Have tried:

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin
set path=C:\Windows\System32\
set path=C:\Windows\System32\*
```

Restarted, but no difference.
Computer is about a year old.  Reinstalled OS a couple of weeks ago due to network port issue.  Been fine until today, ipconfig has been working this week.

Specs:

- Windows 11 Version 21H2 OS Build 22000.652
- Dell Tower PC

Please see current environment variables:

[image]

Comment: [1] if you want to run the built in commands from 'cmd.exe' ... then run that instead of 'powershell.exe'. [*grin*] ///// [2] if you want to set the system Path in a way that sticks beyond the current session ... use the system methods - they can be called from PoSh. lookee ... >>> about Environment Variables - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2#using-the-systemenvironment-methods <<< you want the `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` stuff.

Comment: I know, I know, for the sake of the post I should have used CMD I suppose...  ;)  got a habit of powershell instead of cmd :/     thanks for the info, that command looks good (would it have loaded!!?) but I was still trying to add system paths to `Environment variables` rather then `PATH` which was where I was falling down

Comment: kool! glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the "System Variables" Path doesn't contain `%SystemRoot%\system32`, `%SystemRoot%`. If they are not present, add them manually through GUI, because:

> Have tried:
>
> ```
> set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin
> set path=C:\Windows\System32\
> set path=C:\Windows\System32\*
> ```
>
> Restarted, but no difference.

Those commands only have effect on current shell session, not the whole system, so restarting would make no difference.

FYI: The default value of `PATH` contains `%SystemRoot%\system32`, `%SystemRoot%`, `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`, so if any of these is not there in your `PATH`, you must add them.

Comment: You are THE man.  `PATH` was empty but for ffmpeg and imagemagick paths.  Both recently installed, I'm guessing that one of these installations cleared the rest of the list somehow.  Annoying but sorted now, many thanks.

Comment: You can use setx to update the parameter stick across sessions and reboots. Like `setx path %path%`

Comment: The variable looks like it says $PATH, which suggests a script made for a Unix shell accidentally wiped the variable

Comment: Hmmm...  had the linux subsystem activated before reinstalled the OS.  Haven't done since, but that's the only related thing I can think of...